# Potential problems with having a lot of DB tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

looking for potential problems with having a lot of DB tables inside a single schema of Postgres? I'm talking in 200 table range and primarily looking from performance perspective but any other perspectives are also welcome.

Comment: 200 tables is not considered "lots of tables" - at least not in a single schema. How many schemas of that size do you expect?

Comment: number of tables is pretty much an irrelevant metric.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name actually just 2

Comment: Don't worry with 2 times 200 tables.

Comment: I've seen 600 tables without any issue.